# how to delete a file?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I delete a file, given the full path to the file?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: No i am not receiving error , i want to delete that particular file Block3.xml stored in that particular directory i am not able to judge the syntax for delete

Comment: did you look it up? System.IO.File.Delete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx).

```
File.Delete(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Vijay.EKO-03\Desktop\blockseek3-9-2010\Block3.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var file = new System.IO.File(path);
file.Delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

`File.Delete(string path)` method will work I think.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can just call the static delete method on the file class.

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Vijay.EKO-03\Desktop\blockseek3-9-2010\Block3.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this??? I think it will solve your problems:

```
FileInfo i = new FileInfo("PATH TO YOUR FILE");

i.Delete();
```

Remeber to add:

```
using System.IO;
```