# Deleting csv file using c# code

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to delete a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635659/how-to-delete-a-file)

My application first reads the fields in windows form and then creates a csv file and writes all the fields values in the csv format in it. Then my application reads the csv file and uses it for its further processing. My requirement is that after my application has read the csv file, the file should automatically get deleted(security reasons).

How can i do the above using c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.File.Delete(FilePath)`, where `FilePath` is the file you would like to delete.

[Documentation on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)

If you concerned about security, perhaps you should look into some alternatives to temporarily writing the data to a file on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Call the [`System.IO.File.Delete()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx), and specify the path to the CSV file as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [googling ".NET delete file"](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20delete%20file)? It very quickly points you to [`System.IO.File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another options besides the `System.IO.File.Delete` method is to open the file with a special flag.  Delete *can* fail if the file is still in use by another program (or your code, but let's hope not) that hasn't given `FileShare.Delete` permissions.

An example:

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, 
                              FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None,
                              1024, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
    // do stuff here
}
// file *may* be deleted here if there are no other 
// handles to the file, otherwise it will be deleted
// when all other handles to it are closed, or on 
// system restart
```

That should *guarantee* that the file gets deleted, if you're expecting other programs to hold handles to the file.  If not, it's easier to just use `File.Delete`.